# Programmatically create index

Tags: ravendb

How do I create an index programmatically in RavenDB?

I tried to follow this [example](http://ayende.com/blog/4668/ravendb-defining-indexes).

This is my index creator:

```
public class MyIndex : Raven.Client.Indexes.AbstractIndexCreationTask<MyEntity>
{
    public MyIndex()
    {
        Map = col => col.Select(c => new
        {
            code = c.Code,
            len = c.Code.Length,
            sub = c.Code.Substring(0, 1)
        });
    }
}
```

And here is the caller:

```
var store = new Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore
{
    Url = "http://localhost:8080"
};
store.Initialize();

try
{
    using (var session = store.OpenSession("MyDB"))
    {
        Raven.Client.Indexes.IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(
            typeof(MyIndex).Assembly, store);
    }
}
finally
{
    store.Dispose();
}
```

The index was created but not in MyDB but in system database.

How to create the index in MyDB? Is the way I create index correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:
specify the database name in your store object

```
var store = new Raven.Client.Document.DocumentStore
{
    Url = "http://localhost:8080",
    DefaultDatabase = "MyDB"
};
```

Answer (score 4):

As MED pointed out, you can provide a default database when attaching to the document store.  When doing so, you no longer pass the database name to the `OpenSession` method.  This is the easiest way, and if you're working with a single database then it is the best answer (and should be given the credit as the answer to this question).

But if you need to work with multiple databases, and thus can't use that technique, then you can use this helper method.

```
public static void CreateIndexes(Assembly assembly, IDocumentStore store,
                                                    string databaseName)
{
    var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(assembly);
    var provider = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
    var commands = store.DatabaseCommands.ForDatabase(databaseName);
    IndexCreation.CreateIndexes(provider, commands, store.Conventions);
}
```

Call it the same way you would call the other method, but now you can pass the database name as a parameter.

Comment: I get an error that the provider's SourceProvider is null in raven 2375. Researching this now... Let me know if you have details on that.

Comment: var provider = new CatalogExportProvider(catalog)
                    {
                        SourceProvider = new CatalogExportProvider(catalog)
                    };

fixes my problem and the indexes are created.

Comment: @Steve - thanks for catching that.  Not sure how I got it wrong last time, but it is fixed now.  Your way is good also, but the edit I made is slightly less code to write, and what Raven is doing in its own `CreateIndexes` method anyway.