# OrderBy on a Sub Collection using RavenDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, ravendb

I'm using RavenDB within C# Asp.Net, and I'm having trouble with applying an OrderBy which orders by a value within a sub collection.  A basic example of my model is:

```
public class Record
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name {get; set; }

    public Field[] Fields { get; set; }
}

public class Field
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

This saves down into RavenDB like so

```
{
   "Name": "A Name Of Somesort"
   "Fields": [
       {
          "Name": "Colour",
          "Value": "Red"
       },
       {
          "Name": "Size",
          "Value": "Large"
       }
   ]
}
```

Imagining a large amount of these Records saved into the db, I can get a page of this data like so

```
using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession("TestDB"))
{
    var result = session.Query<Record>().Skip(0).Take(10).ToList();
}
```

What I'd like to do is to be able to sort the records based on a Field value (for example: sort the Records on the Value of a Field whose name is 'Colour')

**Edit:**

To help explain further, what Im wanting to achieve is something like below, however this is not allowed in RavenDB so i need to find an alternative way of doing it (if its even possible)

```
using (var session = documentStore.OpenSession("TestDB"))
{
    var result = session.Query<Record>()
                .OrderBy(v => v.Fields.First(f => f.Name == "Colour").Value)
                .Skip(0)
                .Take(10)
                .ToList();
}
```

This throws a new ArgumentException with the following message

```
Invalid computation: v.Fields.First(f => (f.Name == "Colour")).Value. You cannot use computation (only simple member expression are allowed) in RavenDB queries.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, ive managed to get this working, so just sharing how i did it.

I had to create a new Index like below

```
public class Record_ByField : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Record>
{
    public Record_ByField()
    {
        Map = records=> from r in records
                          select new
                          {
                              _ = r.Fields
                                 .Select(field =>
                                     CreateField(field.Name, field.Value, false, true))
                          };
    }
}
```

This then meant i could use a LuceneQuery to do an OrderBy on a Field value (in this example, on the Values in the Colour Field)

```
var result = session.Advanced.LuceneQuery<Record>("Record/ByField")
            .OrderBy("+Colour")
            .Skip(0)
            .Take(10)
            .ToList();
```

To order by descending, i can replace the + prefix to a - prefix (-Colour), and i can pass any Field Name into this Order By.

For information on progmmatically installing Indexes on a specific Database - see [Programmatically create index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428026/programmatically-create-index)

For information on dynamic Indexes - see http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/client-api/advanced/dynamic-fields

Answer (score 1):

`result.OrderBy(x => x.Field.Name)` will return a collection as LINQ will not change the collection on which it is called rather it returns a new collection which has the required result.

So do

```
result = result.OrderBy(x => x.Field.Name);
```

Comment: Not sure that is what I'm looking for.  Ive added an Edit to hopefully explain further. I'm wanting to sort the list of Records prior to the Skip and Take based on a value of one of the Fields - in the example above it would be on the value of the Field with a Name Colour (so Records with a Field called Colour and Value of Blue would be above a Record with a Field with called Colour and a value of Red)